How to filter relation data in prisma?
I got an error:

→ 60   const schools = await this.prisma.school.findMany(
The column t4.id does not exist in the current database.

The error will only disappear when i remove the line:214-216. But I can't remove these lines since I want to filter the semesters.


const schools = await this.prisma.school.findMany({
  where: {
    semesters: {
      some: {
        isActive: true,
        subjects: {
          none: {},
        },
      },
    },
  },
  select: {
    id: true,
    name: true,
    semesters: {
      where: {
        isActive: true,
        subjects: { // line:214
          none: {}  // line:215
        }           // line:216
      },
      select: { id: true, subjects: { select: { id: true } } },
    },
  },
  take: 100,
});



I know it can be done by the following, but I prefer to the process above.
const schools = ...

const filteredSchools = schools.map(...).filter(...);


If you're getting an error along the lines of The column XXX does not exist in the database, then your Prisma client is out of sync with your database. You may have added an id column to a model, or added a brand new model, to your Prisma schema. But it's not in your database yet, hence the error.
Try running the Prisma migrate command to generate and execute the necessary migration against your database, that way the two are synced up.
npx prisma migrate dev

You'll have to run this command every time you modify your Prisma schema.
Documentation: https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-migrate/workflows/data-migration

i ran the command and i still got an error. Do you have an idea why the error disappear when i remove the line:214-216.

The only thing I can think of is that your database is out of sync with your Prisma schema. Have you tried dropping your local database and then rebuilding it with npx prisma migrate dev to make sure it's up to date?
